# Python: requests.session didn't keep connection alive

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests, keep-alive

My client  kept sending http requests to a nginx server trying to go through the keep-alived link made by requests.Session. But nginx's error.log showed that my client constantly closed the link.

Here's sender part. In fact, my client is an application server keeping sending performance statistic to the nginx.

```
# Init the keep-alived connection when booting the application server
def global_init():
  .......
  global s_perf
  s_perf = requests.Session()

#Send performance statistic
def perf(message):
  s_perf.post('http://127.0.0.1:8180/perf', data=message)
```

Nginx received those statistics correctly. But the logs/error.log show the link were closed frequently:

```
2019/11/18 17:01:43 [info] 61987#61987: *11945220 client 10.32.170.17 closed keepalive connection
2019/11/18 17:01:43 [info] 61992#61992: *11943901 client 10.32.170.17 closed keepalive connection
2019/11/18 17:01:43 [info] 61964#61964: *11945149 client 10.32.170.17 closed keepalive connection
2019/11/18 17:01:43 [info] 61955#61955: *11945286 client 10.32.170.17 closed keepalive connection
2019/11/18 17:01:43 [info] 61973#61973: *11944762 client 10.32.170.17 closed keepalive connection
2019/11/18 17:01:43 [info] 61985#61985: *11945354 client 10.32.170.17 closed keepalive connection
```

Comment: Have you tried defining `s_perf` outside of the function?

Comment: @Fozoro, of course. The code will be raise an exception if it's not.

Comment: The reason is that I misunderstood the log.